# Getting a RSA Cipher's block size

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I have created a `Cipher` using the RSA algorithm and I have a problem when I want to get the block size used. The `Cipher` is declared with the following snippet :

> ```
>         encrypt=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
>          encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,myPublicKey);
> ```

When I try to get the block size with `encrypt.getBlockSize()`, I get "0" which, according to the Javadoc, is the answer when the algorithm used isn't a block cipher, which is not the case of the RSA algorithm.

In debug mode, if I dig into the `Cipher`, I can see in the 'spi' member that a buffer exists, and it's size seems to correspond to the actual block size.

Does anybody know why `getBlockSize()` returns "0" instead of the spi's buffer size?

Comment: I don't think that RSA is a block cipher, so I wouldn't be surprised if it returns 0. AES and DES are block ciphers.

Comment: To be fair, the Java documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher#getBlockSize()) is very succinct. The fact that block ciphers are symmetric only, requires additional knowledge. It's easy for a lay person to assume RSA has blocks and is therefore a block cipher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSA is not considered a block cipher. Block ciphers are symmetric, using the same key to encrypt and decrypt. Unlike AES, where the block size is fixed regardless of the key size, the output of an RSA encryption or signature operation will vary depending on the key size.

If you want to know the size of an RSA cipher text, [examine the modulus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAKey.html#getModulus--) of the key to be used.

Comment: I thought RSA was considered as a block Cipher because data has to be passed to the cipher in blocks (and in opposition to stream ciphers with compute data at the bit level - think I read that on Wikipedia). These blocks have a maximum size, corresponding to the spi's buffer size, and this size is related to the length of the key used (I noticed a size of 53 bytes for a 512 bits key, 117 bytes for a 1024 bits key for encryption and 64 bytes for a 512 bytes key for decryption). I know this question is certainly now out of the scope of this forum but how can I determine that max size?

Comment: @Zelig63 The maximum message size depends on the padding mode as well as the key size. But if you are concerned about the message size, you are doing it wrong. RSA should be used for key transport or digital signature, not direct data encryption. In both of the valid use cases, the size of the message is fixed, and known to be small enough for the RSA operation. You don't encrypt a message with RSA; you encrypt a message with AES, and then encrypt the AES key with RSA.

Answer (score 0):

The interface of the Cipher class does not reveal the allowed input data size and it depends in a non-trivial way from the modulus bit length and applied padding algorithm.

There are the options:

1. [Sun Java] encrypting a block with more than modulus length will raise a `IllegalBlockSizeException` with a message "Data must not be longer than  [n] bytes", may be parsed.
2. [Sun Java] Use reflection to access the length of member `buffer` of Cipher implementation class `RSACipher`
3. [Common] Use a search algorithm to evaluate the maximum allowed input data size, not raising an `IllegalBlockSizeException`.